# C++ "new" in the Java way

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Bjarne Stroustrup, being asked if...

«***Can I use "new" just as in Java?***»

He answered «***Sort of, but don't do it blindly and there are often superior alternatives.***» and showed how to do that, with the following code:

```cpp
void compute(cmplx z, double d)
{
    cmplx z2 = z+d; // c++ style
    z2 = f(z2);     // use z2

    cmplx& z3 = *new cmplx(z+d);    // Java style (assuming Java could overload +)
    z3 = f(z3);
    delete &z3; 
}
```

I tougth that whatever the language be, the **"new"** works in the same manner i.e. allocates space for an object and assigns a pointer with the address of that object.

I'm wondering what's the difference (in terms of performence or whatsoever) between:

```cpp
MyClass *ptr = new MyClass();
...
delete ptr;
```

and

```cpp
MyClass& ref = *new MyClass();
...
delete &ref;
```

Any ideas about this?

Thank you

Comment: `delete &ref` smells like bad code. If one has to type anything like it, they are doing it wrong. As for the general difference between reference and pointer, this is a dupe of a dupe of a dupe.

Comment: There is no difference, whatsoever, in terms of performance, and I would expect most compilers to spit out identical code for both. The second version is just more convoluted.

Comment: @SergeyA, can you please post here the link of the other question? Before I post, I searched and found nothing.

Comment: @SergeyA, ok, I already read. It's not easy to catch all questions posted before even with the sugestions that the site points.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, thank you for your answer. «I would expect most compilers to spit out identical code for both» is a smart observation not obvious to all people.

Comment: It is certainly  obvious to me. The code does exactly the same thing: why would the compiler do anything different?

Comment: @EJP, **1)** cout << ++x;  **2)** cout << x+1;  are you **100% certain** that **ALL** compilers generate the same code?